# OpenCV in Java for Image Filtering

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, imagefilter

i have java codes from Tutorials Point. This code for Robinson filter.

```
package improctry2;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


public class ImProcTry2 {
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
   try {
      int kernelSize = 9;
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      Mat source = Highgui.imread("grayscale.jpg",
      Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
      Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());
      Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_32F){
      {
         put(0,0,-1);
         put(0,1,0);
         put(0,2,1);

         put(1,0-2);
         put(1,1,0);
         put(1,2,2);

         put(2,0,-1);
         put(2,1,0);
         put(2,2,1);
      }
      };          
      Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
      Highgui.imwrite("output.jpg", destination);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xyagb2xt03nkyp/grayscale.jpg?dl=0) is is my image input, and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsuzmlp7o5ap4a5/output.jpg?dl=0) the output (i can't post the pictures because i'm new in stackoverflow).
As you can see, the image turn into black and nothing appears. I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0 and i already put the OpenCV library in Netbeans. I also run another OpenCV Java codes and they work very well. And i also run this code in Eclipse but the result is same.
Anybody can help me?
Thank You

Comment: This link has been broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a 9x9 kernel matrix, but then fill only a 3x3 submatrix of it, leaving other elements unititialized. To fix it, just change:

```
int kernelSize = 9;
```

to:

```
int kernelSize = 3;
```

Your code actually works in the newest Opencv (3.0 beta), but those unititialized elements break it in older versions (I checked 2.4.10). To print elements of a matrix use:

```
System.out.println(kernel.dump());
```

PS.
Welcome to stackoverflow. :)